# How to move PHPunit 4.8 to the path?

Tags: path, composer-php, ubuntu-14.04

Hi I try to install PHPunit on my 14.04 ubuntu, but newest version require PHP 5.6 and I got only 5.5 so I installed PHPUnit

via composer `composer global require "phpunit/phpunit = 4.8.*"`

But when I try to access it `phpunit -c app/`

I get `bash: usr/local/bin/PHPUnit: No such file or directory`

How to move it to the path?

Comment: Follow [this link](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally) maybe help you install composer global as you want

Comment: Thanks to u I tried different google approach, and come up with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://akrabat.com/global-installation-of-php-tools-with-composer/) link explains how to add all composer installed tools to the path.